# Playing Mass Effect 3 without XBox Live - Any other way to boost galactic readiness?

Tags: mass-effect-3-multiplayer, mass-effect-3

My XBox Live just expired, and I dont want to buy it again for another year only for ME3.

I heard I'll be missing on for galactic readiness, lowering my chances for the good ending.

Is there another way to boost galactic readiness that is not tied to multiplayer?

Comment: Do you own an iPhone or iOS device?

Comment: I do. What is with it?

Comment: You know you can just re-up for a month, yeah?  There's no need to buy a whole year.  Also, if your XBL subscription just ran out, it's likely you'll have cheap offers on the dashboard to renew.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the iOS apps, which I noted in this answer:

[Will I miss out on anything by not playing Mass Effect 3's multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53671/will-i-miss-out-on-anything-by-not-playing-mass-effect-3s-multiplayer/53674#53674)

You also get a 2-day Xbox Live Gold card in with the game.  If you use this time strategically (ie, as you're nearing the end of the game) you might be able to spend a weekend playing the multiplayer mode to boost your readiness score.  (Remember that it [decays over time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53929/how-fast-does-galactic-readiness-decay) so you can't just use it whenever and expect to keep the bonuses.)

If you're anything like me, you've probably also got a few more of these codes kicking around.  I'm not sure what the limit is on their use, but you might be able to buy yourself just enough time to get by.

Also note that if you haven't already taken advantage of it, each console has a limited number of "free month" Xbox Live Gold offers.  If you create a new profile, and sign up for Silver, there's a chance you'll be offered a month of Gold for free.

Any of these methods would likely get you enough time to make an impact on your overall score, but remember that you can still get the best ending by just playing single player.

Answer (score 2):

There IS another way!

You can download the game Mass Effect:Infiltrator from the App Store for an iOS device (iPod Touch, iPhone, iPad). It costs $6.99 (US) as of 3/7/12, and completing objectives in the game will allow you to increase your Galactic Readiness score!

There is also a free Mass Effect: Datapad app due out later this week, which is supposed to be free and offer additional ways to raise galactic Readiness. Datapad is more of a lore/news app and less of a game, so it's unclear exactly how much using it will enable you to contribute to Galactic Readiness.

Answer (score 1):

If you own an iOS device, you can improve your galactic readiness by downloading and playing the iOS game, [Mass Effect: Infiltrator](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect:_Infiltrator). This costs $6.99, though.

There are also plans for another app, [Mass Effect: Datapad](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect:_Datapad) that will provide similar functionality, though it's not going to be a third person shooter like Infiltrator.

Finally, it bears mentioning that a galactic readiness of 50% (the default, and lowest possible value) is still more than enough to beat the game. Increasing your galactic readiness is by no means mandatory to completely fill the bar before you launch the final assault.