# Mass Effect 3: Levels and cooldowns

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Does the level in single player in any way affect the Multiplayer game? Because i have been playing and even tho i chose to go mainly for cooldowns they just won't go lower than 3,7-4,2 seconds. And still i can see people using their powers faster? I have tried with the omni-capasitor IV and with the Expert package V, but it doesn't seem to affect the tech or bio cooldowns in any way?

And does promote do anything other then giving me challenge points? or is that all it does?

Any answers will be helpful, Thanks =)

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55602/how-are-cooldowns-calculated

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53535/does-the-mass-effect-3-multiplayer-component-has-any-effect-on-the-single-player?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

No, your singleplayer progress has no effect on multiplayer whatsoever.